# Getting last character/number of data frame column

Tags: r, substr, string-length

I'm trying to get the last character or number of a series of symbols on data frame so I can filter some categories after. But I'm not getting the expected result.

```
names = as.character(c("ABC Co","DEF Co","XYZ Co")) 
code = as.character(c("ABCN1","DEFMO2","XYZIOIP4")) #variable length
my_df = as.data.frame(cbind(names,code))
```

First Approach:

```
my_df[,3] = substr(my_df[,2],length(my_df[,2]),length(my_df[,2]))
```

What I expected to receive was: `c("1","2","4")`

What I am really receiving is : `c("C","F","Z")`

Then, I realized that `length(my_df[,2])` is the number of rows of my data frame, and not the length of each cell. So, I decided to create this loop:

```
for (i in length(nrow(my_df))){
  my_df[i,3] = substr(my_df[i,2],length(my_df[i,2]),length(my_df[i,2]))
}
```

What I expected to receive was: `c("1","2","4")`

What I am really receiving is : `c("A","F","Z")`

So then I tried:

```
for (i in length(nrow(my_df))){
  my_df[i,3] = substr(my_df[i,2],-1,-1)
}
```

What I expected to receive was: `c("1","2","4")`

What I am really receiving is : `c("","F","Z")`

Not getting any luck, any thoughts of what am I missing? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`length` is a *vector* (or *list*) property, whereas in `substr` you probably need a *string* property. Base R's `nchar` works.

```r
my_df = as.data.frame(cbind(names, code), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
substr(my_df[,2], nchar(my_df[,2]), nchar(my_df[,2]))
# [1] "1" "2" "4"
```

(I added `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, otherwise you'll need to add `as.character`.)

Answer (score 1):

If the last character is always a number you can do:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(my_df$code, "\\d$")
[1] "1" "2" "4"
```

If the last character can be anything you can do this:

```
str_extract(my_df$code, ".$")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr`:

```
my_df$last_char <- substr(code, nchar(code), nchar(code))
# or my_df$last_char <- substr(my_df$code, nchar(my_df$code), nchar(my_df$code))
```

Output

```
my_df

#   names     code last_char
# 1 ABC Co    ABCN1         1
# 2 DEF Co   DEFMO2         2
# 3 XYZ Co XYZIOIP4         4
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub`

```
 sub(".*(\\d+$)", "\\1", my_df$code)
```